# WordPress Multisite SubDomains - two installations conflict

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I have a problem with WordPress multisite in subdomains mode - I have made two installations under addresses like:

```
domain.com - first multisite WP,
tools.domain.com - second multisite WP
```

Everything works fine, for example:

```
domain.com,
site1.domain.com,
site2.domain.com,
tools.domain.com.
```

The one thing that DOES NOT WORK is:

```
site1.tools.domain.com
```

(or any other site name).

This very last request gets redirected to:

```
domain.com/wp-signup.php?new=site1.tools
```

like it is non existing site for first WP installation.

I checked a lot of times DNS zones entries, tried a lot of times, waited a lot more time to see is there any delay with DNS propagation. And still can't get it working right.

My host's support suggested changes withing .htaccess for main domain but I'm not sure how.